# MySQL debugging tool slow queries?

Tags: mysql

What are the free tools available to find the slow queries of MySQL? apart from logging the slow queries.

Need to analysis the slow queries in detail.

Thanks,
Kathir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this tool - [Neor Profile SQL](http://www.profilesql.com/).

*Neor Profile SQL - an application that catches all requests from the client and works as a proxy server. This technology allows you to take under control all access to the database and identify bottlenecks in requests.*

Comment: my antivirus is blocking it...

Answer (score 10):

Use [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html). Example:

```
explain select * from your_table
```

Comment: Totally forgot what word to use before a query to debug it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `EXPLAIN` and `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` statements can be used either as a way to obtain information about how MySQL executes a statement. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html