# How to debug/view SQL requests with Laravel / Laragon

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laragon

My question is very simple but I have no clue: I have always been working with java and eclipse or C# until now so it's a "new world" :)

How can I debug my laravel code?

I am using laravel and vuejs. I start my server with laragon, and I use VScode. I have tried starting it from VScode (added xdebug dll in laragon) but it doesn't give me more info, and I don't manage to debug anything using breakpoints:

```
{
    "name": "Launch localhost",
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1/",
    "webRoot": "C://laragon//www//projet"
},
{
    "name": "Launch index.php",
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "file": "C://laragon//www//projet//index.php"
},
```

When I get an error with sql, all I get is

```
app.js:651 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (app.js:651)
    at settle (app.js:814)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (app.js:184)
```

How can I see my SQL request and get the "real error"?
And how can I properly debug?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You can take a look on `laravel.log`, all errors are stored there

Comment: Also MySQL `explain` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842952/mysql-debugging-tool-slow-queries

Comment: Thanks, and there is no possibility to have display it in vscode or command line for all requests / all errors? And to debug with breakpoints?

Comment: You can debug php with `xdebug`, can't tell you exactly about VSCode

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple options to achieve the SQL logging:

1.Use query listener by registering it in service provider (boot method as follow)

```
namespace App\Providers;
 
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use DB;
use Log;
 

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
 
        DB::listen(function($query) {
            Log::info(
                $query->sql,
                $query->bindings,
                $query->time
            );
        });
    }
}
```

2. Use Query logging please refer to https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#query-logging
3. Use laravel debugger package please refer to  https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

You can debug php with xdebug but i would still prefer any option among above 3.

Comment: For some reason I don't see anything in my console when adding it. It may be because i have 2 databases, not sure... I add your code for both.
DB::connection('mysql1')->enableQueryLog();
DB::connection('mysql2')->enableQueryLog();
But i can't see anything in my chrome console. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry for the late response @Maxiss, I have updated the link for option 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel Debugbar to see the real time queries. It provides many other useful information for debugging purpose. Please check this link https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Also try to log the collection into SQL using query listener by registering it inside service provider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        DB::listen(function ($query) {

            // $query->sql
            // $query->bindings
            // $query->time

            Log::useDailyFiles(storage_path().'/logs/query_log.log');
            $query = $query->sql;
            Log::info($query);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I installed Laravel Debugbar and it appeared twice but for some reason I can't get it anymore... I spend a lot hours trying to make it work now. 
Andso, when adding your boot function, am I supposed to get the log in the chrome console? I only get the error.
app.js:1154 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500 even though I wrote Log::info($request); and Debugbar::info($request);